# Detect property value change in observable collection using ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui

This collection of object

```
[Reactive] public ObservableCollection<PIObj> ListLine { get; set; }
```

And this was the code that can only detect collection changed. What I tried to do is, **how to detect any property value changed in that collection.** Can someone help me?

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ListLine)
            .Where(y => y is object)
            .Select(collection => collection.ToObservableChangeSet())
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"Set Changed"));
```

Comment: Might want to look at https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData#observing-properties-of-objects-in-a-collection

Comment: I try to `var changed = ListLine.Connect().WhenAnyPropertyChanged();`

and got this error  _Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0311 The type 'Test.PIObj' cannot be used as type parameter 'TObject' in the generic type or method 'ObservableListEx.WhenAnyPropertyChanged<TObject>(IObservable<IChangeSet<TObject>>, params string[])'.'._

Comment: You'll likely want to keep your ToObservableChangeSet() approach since it's not SourceList or SourceCache.